# Python WSGI Error on Output

Tags: python, mod-wsgi, wsgi

My python has become quite rusty as I haven't used it for quite a while and am stuck with an issue I am not able to figure out.

The python program should accept a form's data sent by a web page, and return some JSON response codes back to it. Everything works fine except when the data is sent:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    """ Process the form data, spit out the reponse """

    # code here extracts the form 
    # data and the response code is 
    # stored in info

    # everything done, output now
    output(environ, start_response, info)


def output(environ, start_response, info):
    
    # debug
    print >> environ['wsgi.errors'], "BACK TO THE BROWSER"

    feedback = json.dumps(info)
    
    # debug
    print >> environ['wsgi.errors'], feedback
    
    status = "200 OK"
    headers = [('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'), ('Content-Length', str(len(feedback)))]
    start_response(status, headers)
    return [feedback]
```

The error log says:

> ...
> [wsgi:error] ... BACK TO THE BROWSER
>
> [wsgi:error] ... {"errors": [1430360477881, 1430233459050]}
>
> [wsgi:error] ... mod_wsgi (pid=1654): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/tmp/mod_wsgi-localhost:8000:0/htdocs/'.
>
> [wsgi:error] ... TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
> ...

Ok, Python is complaining that something it expects to be iterable is None. But which iterable is Python complaining about in this function? (Note that I am using mod_wsgi directly without any frameworks / modules).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return the response:

```
return output(environ, start_response, info)
```

Comment: So basically, for WSGI the input and the output both have to be from the same function (`application()` here, in the case of mod_wsgi)?

Comment: WSGI requires `application` to take the request and return an iterable response.

Comment: More details can be found in [PEP 3333](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3333/)