# uwsgi published Python 3.4 app, env['wsgi.errors'] = <_io.TextIOWrapper name=2 mode='w' encoding='ANSI_X3.4-1968'>

Tags: python, web-deployment, uwsgi

I am learning basics of webdev. I got working python3.4 app published with uwsgi.
It works fine (outputs env dictionary with Jinja2 template engine), but I cannot find what that header means:

```
env['wsgi.errors'] = <_io.TextIOWrapper name=2 mode='w' encoding='ANSI_X3.4-1968'>
```

Do I need to fix something or its just like an object link?

**EDIT:**

To be more specific, here is example of code that I am talking about:

```
def application(env, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type','text/html')])
    return [b"Hello World"]
```

Like it described [here](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html#the-first-wsgi-application)

**EDIT2:**

[Link to that app](https://webdev.bekhterev.me/headers) with headers output

Comment: *Where* are you getting this?

Comment: env - is a dictionary, containing request headers and other stuff related. 'wsgi.errors' is a key in that ditctionary.[link] (https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html#the-first-wsgi-application)

Comment: I edited my post, hope now it is more clear what and where I am getting this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not an error, its an object, where you can write errors to uwsgi server log.

For example:

```
def application(env, start_response):
    print('Hello, Lepra!', file=env['wsgi.errors'])
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type','text/html')])
    return [b"Hello World"]
```

Links:

- [Python WSGI Error on Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29959267/python-wsgi-error-on-output)
- [www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3333/](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3333/)